# A binary search implementation for any datatype in C (continuation)

Tags: beginner, algorithm, c, pointers, binary-search

This is an indirect follow-up to [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/176727/a-linear-search-implementation-for-any-data-type-in-c).

I've tried to assimilate all that was instructed and here's my attempt at binary search.

### `binary_search.h`

```
#ifndef _BINARY_SEARCH_H
#define _BINARY_SEARCH_H

/*
 * Summary:
 *  Performs binary search on the given sorted array using the given
 * comparator function. Returns the index of the matching array
 * element (< count), and -1 if the element is not found.
 *
 *  Parameters are independent of type and hence this function
 * can be used for arrays of all data-types, provided that the size
 * (i.e. in terms of bytes) is properly specified.
 *
 * CAUTION: It will not work on unsorted arrays.
 *
 * Parameters:
 *  1. *x    - the address of the element to find in the array
 *  2. *base - the address of the sorted array from whence we start searching.
 *  3. count - the maximum number of elements we are willing to search against.
 *  4. size  - the size of each element of the array (in bytes)
 *  5. compare(void*, void*)
 *           - the function which is used for comparison. Zero is taken to be equality.
 */
void *binary_search(const void *x, const void *base, size_t count, size_t size,
                    int (*compare)(const void *, const void *));

#endif
```

### `binary_search.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void *binary_search(const void *x, const void *base, size_t count, size_t size,
                    int (*compare)(const void *, const void *))
{
    char *base_ptr = (char *) base;
    size_t lo = 0, hi = count - 1, mid;
    while (lo <= hi) {
        mid = lo + ((hi - lo) >> 1);
        int result = (*compare)(base_ptr + mid * size, x);
        if (result == 0) {
            return base_ptr + mid * size;
        } else if (result < 0) {
            lo = mid + 1;
        } else {
            hi = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

### `main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "binary_search.h"

int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const double *p = a;
    const double *q = b;
    // The convention is to send the NaNs to the end, so
    // they are considered to be greater than others here.
    if (isnan(*p)) return +1;
    if (isnan(*q)) return -1;
    // An elegant way to convert the result to int:
    return (*p > *q) - (*p < *q);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    double *a, *result;
    double x;
    size_t size, count, i;
    double aa = .1, bb = .1;
    size = sizeof(double);

    printf("Enter how many elements : ");
    scanf("%llu", &count);

    a = malloc(count * size);
    if (a == NULL) {
        printf("Error while trying to allocate memory.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Enter elements one-by-one:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%u : ", (i + 1));
        scanf("%lf", (a + i));
    }

    printf("Enter the element to look for : ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    result = binary_search(&x, a, count, size, compare);

    if (result) {
        printf("Element found. Index is %u\n", (result - a));
    } else {
        printf("Element not found.\n");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Same request. Suggestions and critique are welcome.

---

### Update

In `main.c`, the line `double aa = .1, bb = .1;` is unnecessary. I forgot to remove it after debugging. You may disregard it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code does not handle an array size of 0 (`count == 0`). Simple to fix

```
//size_t lo = 0, hi = count - 1, mid;
//while (lo <= hi) {

size_t lo = 0, hi = count, mid;
while (lo < hi) {
  hi--;
```

Potential UB.  Consider the below if `mid == 0`.  IMO, better to use a variable `hi_plus_1` instead of `hi` and adjust code accordingly to avoid `size_t` *underflow*.

```
        hi = mid - 1;  // hi could become SIZE_MAX
```

Avoid losing `const`-ness.

```
const void *base
// char *base_ptr = (char *) base;
const char *base_ptr = (const char *) base;
```

`binary_search.c` is missing the include of `binary_search.h`.  This is important to maintain the consistency of the declaration and definition.

`binary_search.h` should include `<stdlib.h>` for `size_t`.

```
#include "binary_search.h"

void *binary_search(const void *x, const void *base, size_t count, size_t size,
    int (*compare)(const void *, const void *)) {
  const char *base_ptr = (const char *) base;
  size_t lo = 0, hi_plus1 = count;
  while (lo < hi) {
    size_t mid = lo + (hi_plus1 - lo)/2;
    int result = (*compare)(base_ptr + mid * size, x);
    if (result == 0) {
      return base_ptr + mid * size;
    } else if (result < 0) {
      lo = mid + 1;
    } else {
      hi_plus1 = mid;
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

---

Test code

Problem specifier.  Use `"%zu"` for `size_t`.  The 2 below hint OP is not compiling with all warnings enabled.  Double-check that all warnings are enabled for prompt automatic feedback.

```
 size_t count, i;
 // scanf("%llu", &count);
 scanf("%zu", &count);

 for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    // printf("%u : ", (i + 1));
    printf("%zu : ", (i + 1));
```

A size of 0 may cause for `malloc()` to return `NULL` and that is not an out-of-memory.

```
 a = malloc(count * size);
 // if (a == NULL) {
 if (a == NULL && count > 0) {
   printf("Error while trying to allocate memory.\n");
```

`size = sizeof(double);` lacks context.  Why `sizeof(double)`?  Certainly that is because that is the type `a` points to.  Then code that directly:

```
// size = sizeof(double);
size = sizeof *a;
```

For testing, useful to print the value sought and the value found.  Recommend `%e` for detail.

```
printf("Value sought %e\n", x);
printf("Value found  %e\n", x, *result);
// or for sufficient detail
printf("Value sought %.*e\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, x);
printf("Value found  %.*e\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, *result);
```

With `compare()`, note that `0.0` will match `-0.0`.  If that is not desired, perhaps below.  Simplifications may be possible.

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const double *p = a;
    const double *q = b;
    if (*a > *b) return 1;
    if (*a < *b) return -1;
    if (isnan(*p)) return +1;
    if (isnan(*q)) return -1;

    // values are equal and not NaNs
    if (!signbit(*a) == !signbit(*b)) return 0;
    if (signbit(*a)) return -1;
    return 1;
}
```